# How do I download all files listed in an array?

Tags: shell-script, wget, array

I want to download all files in [this GitHub directory](https://github.com/JeffHoogland/bodhi3packages/tree/master/bodhi-profile-moksha/usr/share/enlightenment/data/config/bodhi) to `/usr/share/enlightenment/data/config`. I have this script:

```
L=('e.cfg' 'e_randr.cfg' 'exehist.cfg' 'module.battery.cfg' 'module.clock.cfg' 'module.conf.cfg' 'module.everything-apps.cfg' 'module.everything-files.cfg' 'module.everything.cfg' 'module.gadman.cfg' 'module.ibar.cfg' 'module.notification.cfg' 'module.pager.cfg' 'module.syscon.cfg' 'module.tasks.cfg')
pushd /usr/share/enlightenment/data/config
for i in $L
do
  sudo wget -c $JEF/$i #$JEF is defined in my ~/.bashrc script
done
popd
```

but it just downloads `e.cfg` and that is it.

Comment: Your code is correct `zsh` syntax, not in other shells.

Comment: I would avoid running `wget` as superuser. A few vulnerabilities have been found in `wget` in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Fewer quotes, parethesis, and brackets, and other syntax!:

```
L='e.cfg e_randr.cfg exehist.cfg etc'

for i in $L
do
  echo wget -c "$JEF/$i" #$JEF is defined in my ~/.bashrc script
done
```

This is oldest and most common way to do it.  More people understand this.  Arrays are extensions that I have never used.

Comment: Missing the pushd and popd. Long lines should be avoided where possible.

Comment: It should be noted that It assumes IFS contains the space character and that none of the characters in those elements (and `$JEF`) appear in `$IFS` or are wildcard characters. Arrays were created to address those kind of issues.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  Agreed.  Good to know the caveats.  In this case the elements are static strings.  Isn't it extremely unlikely that this code would run without a space in IFS?  I've scripted IFS=... but only in very controlled conditions, usually in a subshell.  I've never seen it set globally or in the environment. Also agree, almost all variable references should be quoted, adding that.

Answer (score 6):

In `bash` or `ksh`, you need to iterate over all the elements of the array with:

```
for i in "${L[@]}"; do wget ....; done
```

`${L[@]}` will be expanded to all elements of the array `L` and `for` is used to iterate over those.

If you use `$L` is `bash` or `ksh`, it will behave as `${L[0]}` i.e. in your case, you will get only the first element of the array.

Comment: +1. and don't forget to `"` quote `$i` as `"$i"` every time you use it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer, myself, by looking at [Array variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) in The Bash Beginners' Guide.

This is what the script should be:

```
L=('e.cfg' 'e_randr.cfg' 'exehist.cfg' 'module.battery.cfg' 'module.clock.cfg' 'module.conf.cfg' 'module.everything-apps.cfg' 'module.everything-files.cfg' 'module.everything.cfg' 'module.gadman.cfg' 'module.ibar.cfg' 'module.notification.cfg' 'module.pager.cfg' 'module.syscon.cfg' 'module.tasks.cfg')
pushd /usr/share/enlightenment/data/config
for i in ${L[*]}
do
  sudo wget -c $JEF/$i
done
popd
```

Comment: Don't use `${L[*]}`, use `${L[@]}` instead as my answer suggested..

Comment: It worked though, why should I use `${L[@]}` instead?

Comment: Yes, use ${L[@]}, and get into the habit of quoting!!! it: "${L[@]}"

Comment: Unquoted both `${L[*]}`, and `${L[@]}` work equivalently. When quoted, the `*` option joins each value with the first character of IFS (become one long value unless re-split), the `@` option keeps each value separate.

Comment: Try `L=(a b c d); printf "<%s>\n" "${L[*]}"; printf "<%s>\n" "${L[@]}"`. See the difference?